# Combine two regexes

Tags: regex

I have two regular expressions which are working perfectly fine when use independently.

```
First  : ^.+\.((jpeg)|(gif)|(png))\s*$ : search for .jpeg,gif or png at the end of url 
Second : ^.+(javax.faces.resource|rfRes).* : search for two url patterns
```

I want to combine the above two expressions such that " url ends in any of the image " OR "url has javax.faces.resource or rfRes in its path"

I tried using | operator to join both but it seems its not working like below :

```
^.+\.((jpeg)|(gif)|(png))\s*$ | ^.+(javax.faces.resource|rfRes).*
```

but its not working.

Can anybody please help in joining above two regex ?

Comment: Why combining? Just check if both are true or something..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have extra spaces around the `|` operator:

```
Your original regex
^.+\.((jpeg)|(gif)|(png))\s*$ | ^.+(javax.faces.resource|rfRes).*
^.+\.((jpeg)|(gif)|(png))\s*$|^.+(javax.faces.resource|rfRes).*
Fixed regex                  ^
                             |
```

Your solution will try to match "the end of the string *and then a space*," or "a space *and then the beginning of the string*." Remember, whitespace is significant in regexes.

Comment: Ha, I completely missed it... This is the right solution, +1. An alternative is to use e`X`tended flag.

Comment: @Doorknob:Thanks for help. It worked.I realy missed whitespaces

Answer (score 2):

The spaces in your combined expression are erroneous.  You are requiring a space after end of line or before beginning of line, which is impossible in line-oriented input.

As a further improvement, you can remove the superfluous "anything" parts of the match, as well as a good number of redundant parentheses.

```
javax\.faces\.resource|rfRes|\.(jpeg|gif|png)\s*$
```

Notice also the proper quoting of literal full stop characters (a lone `.` matches any character).